# mongoc library & cross compile for ARM

Tags: mongodb, compilation, x86, cross-compiling, raspbian

I try to compile the mongo c driver using an Ubuntu system to target the raspbian x86 architecture.

I'm using the toolchains provided by Raspberry and Here what I do :

```
git clone https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-c-driver.git
cd mongo-c-driver
./autogen.sh
./configure --host=arm-linux-gnueabihf --target=arm-linux-gnueabihf --with-libbson=bundled --enable-tests=no --enable-examples=no --enable-static --disable-shared
```

But it compiles for x64 :

```
objdum -a ./libs/libmongoc-1.0.&
```

> File format elf64-x86-64

What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

```
$ ./configure --help
```

Describes the env vars to set your cross compiler

```
$ export CC=[PATH]/arm-linux-gnueabihf-cpp
$ export CXX=[PATH]/arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++
```